# How to realize += delegate (...) construction with Visual C++?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

Here is a fragment of code based on C#:

```
connectionInfo.AuthenticationPrompt += delegate (object sender01, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs en)
{
      foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in en.Prompts)
      {
           if (prompt.Request.Equals("Password: ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
           {
               prompt.Response = passwordValue;
           }
      }
};
```

Could you help me please with writing of this code in Visual C++?
Specially with this operation:

```
connectionInfo.AuthenticationPrompt += delegate (object sender01, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs en)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `connectionInfo.AuthenticationPrompt` have an `operator+=` that takes a `std::function<void( Object, AuthenticationPromptEventArg )>` as argument. Express the `delegate` as a lambda. That's it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-)
But could you write in details how it looks in my case?
I never worked with the lamba expressions...

Comment: @YuriBodrov: It looks like you're using some over-engineered framework in C#, and doing it in C++ might give you a chance to simplify and solidify. An example is given in [V.Kravchenko's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34806950/464581). I would let `operator+` return `void` for there is no point in supporting code-with-side-effects at a cost of verbosity and possible (marginal) inefficiency, but note that the standard library containers require that pure copy assignment returns reference to self, in a case of paying for what you never use.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again! :-) Will think hard! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like

```
template <typename TArg>
class Event {
public:
    //....
    typedef std::function<void (TArg)> Delegate;
    Event & operator += (const Delegate & arg)
    {
        //...
        //Add delegate to delegate collection
        return *this;
    }
};
```

So that it can be used like

```
//...
Event<int> valueChanged;
//...
valueChanged += [&values](int newValue) { values.push_back(newValue); };
```

To extend, you can use variadic argument template instead of single TArg.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! :-)